# Manipulate options in a form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I googled a lot, but I am a rookie in JS and HTML. I have a problem I can not solve.

I do have that html form (hope I copy it in right):

```
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Geschlecht</legend>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="s_radio" id="s_radio1" value="m" checked="checked">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="s_radio1">
                        M&auml;nnlicher K&ouml;rper
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="s_radio" id="s_radio2" value="f">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="s_radio2">
                        Weiblicher K&ouml;rper
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">K&ouml;rperfettanteil</legend>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <select class="form-control" id="kfaform">
                    <option value="3.5">3-4 %</option>
                    <option value="6.5">6-7 %</option>
                    <option value="11">10-12 %</option>
                    <option value="15">15 %</option>
                    <option value="20">20 %</option>
                    <option value="25">25 %</option>
                    <option value="30">30 %</option>
                    <option value="35">35 %</option>
                    <option value="40">40 %</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

The first radio button is checked standard and the options in the control form are ok like that.

But if the second radio button get checked by a user the form should include other options like:

```
<option value="11">10-12 %</option>
<option value="16">15-17 %</option>
<option value="21">20-22 %</option>
<option value="25">25 %</option>
<option value="30">30 %</option>
<option value="35">35 %</option>
<option value="40">40 %</option>
<option value="45">45 %</option>
<option value="50">50 %</option>
```

AND the options that were in the form before should get deleted.

Very important:
It has to go both ways which means if you click the first radio button again it should change back to first state.

Hope you understand my problem.

I am thankful for every tip.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to look into using React to update states of other elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added classes to your options list. I then use JS to listen for clicks to your radio buttons and hide and display the respective options accordingly:

```js
function start() {
  setMannOptions();
  //
  document.getElementById("s_radio1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    setMannOptions();
  });
  document.getElementById("s_radio2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    setWeibOptions();
  });

}

function setMannOptions() {
  var weib = document.getElementsByClassName("weib");
  if (weib) {
    for (x = 0; x < weib.length; x++) {
      weib[x].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  //
  var mann = document.getElementsByClassName("mann");
  if (mann) {
    for (x = 0; x < mann.length; x++) {
      mann[x].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}

function setWeibOptions() {
  var mann = document.getElementsByClassName("mann");
  if (mann) {
    for (x = 0; x < mann.length; x++) {
      mann[x].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  //
  var weib = document.getElementsByClassName("weib");
  if (weib) {
    for (x = 0; x < weib.length; x++) {
      weib[x].style.display = "block";
    }
  }

}

document.onload = start();
```

```html
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Geschlecht</legend>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="s_radio" id="s_radio1" value="m" checked="checked">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="s_radio1">
                        M&auml;nnlicher K&ouml;rper
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="s_radio" id="s_radio2" value="f">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="s_radio2">
                        Weiblicher K&ouml;rper
                    </label>
      </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>


<fieldset class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">K&ouml;rperfettanteil</legend>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="form-check">
        <select class="form-control" id="kfaform">
          <option value="" selected></option>
          <option value="3.5" class="mann">3-4 %</option>
          <option value="6.5" class="mann">6-7 %</option>
          <option value="11" class="mann">10-12 %</option>
          <option value="15" class="mann">15 %</option>
          <option value="20" class="mann">20 %</option>
          <option value="25" class="mann">25 %</option>
          <option value="30" class="mann">30 %</option>
          <option value="35" class="mann">35 %</option>
          <option value="40" class="mann">40 %</option>
          <option value="11" class="weib">10-12 %</option>
          <option value="16" class="weib">15-17 %</option>
          <option value="21" class="weib">20-22 %</option>
          <option value="25" class="weib">25 %</option>
          <option value="30" class="weib">30 %</option>
          <option value="35" class="weib">35 %</option>
          <option value="40" class="weib">40 %</option>
          <option value="45" class="weib">45 %</option>
          <option value="50" class="weib">50 %</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Looks good. One small point - changing selected radio buttons doesn't nuke the currently selected option in the select list. To reproduce: (0)select Mann radio button (1) select 20% in drop-down. (2) select Weib radio-button. !!! Oops, the drop-down still says 20%, even though this value is not in the new list. Querying the drop-down does indeed return a value of 20.

Comment: I tried finding how to cleat the displayed value. I only find how to clear everything in the dropdown.

Can you help me which function I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem enhzflep found like this:

```
  setMannOptions();
  //
  document.getElementById("s_radio1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    $('#kfaform option').prop('selected', function() {
        return this.defaultSelected;
    });
  $("#kfaform option:first").attr("selected", true);
    setMannOptions();
  });
  document.getElementById("s_radio2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    $('#kfaform option').prop('selected', function() {
        return this.defaultSelected;
    });

  ("#kfaform option:first").attr("selected", true);
    setWeibOptions();
  });
}
```

Now everything works fine.

Thx a lot for the very fast response!